# AppDelegate.m:40:5: Use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate'

Tags: javascript, react-native

This error i faced when implemented `react-native-fbsdk-next`.
I guess an import is missing in app delegate.m

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

Add in your /AppDelegate.m the following line.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```